# How do I make my bootstrap form responsive?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I couldn't seem to get my form responsive. It works fine with desktop view.

I'm a beginner and I am absolutely clueless... Need help with this, would appreciate the kind gesture.

Here's the code snippet:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row mt-1">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
      <form action="https://formspree.io/mvowablq" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Name:</label>
          <input
            type="name"
            class="form-control"
            id="name"
            placeholder="Enter name"
            name="name"
          />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="email">Email:</label>
          <input
            type="email"
            class="form-control"
            id="email"
            placeholder="Enter email"
            name="_replyto"
          />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="message">Message:</label>
          <textarea
            class="form-control"
            name="message"
            id="message"
            cols="30"
            rows="10"
          ></textarea>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send</button>

      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
      <img
        class="img-fluid"
        src="/Selected - Contact/7DFB6BE4-B9D8-470A-8A4F-AF11EFA7F565.png"
        alt=""
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: _..I'm a beginner and I am absolutely clueless...._ Read over [bootstrap getting-started](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/)

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap is already responsive if installed correctly. Do you have `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` in your header?

Comment: yes I do have that in my header. But still doesn't work